# Wrong UIBarButtonItem positioning when going from search result table

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating a UIBarButtonItem on the right side of my navigation bar with this code:

```
-(void)setupImageTrashButton {
    UIButton *menuButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIImage *backgroundColor = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trash"];
    [menuButton setImage:backgroundColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[menuButton imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    UIBarButtonItem *barMenuButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuButton];
    [menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(delete) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barMenuButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
}
```

It work properly except when I reach that ViewController from a search result table (clicking on a search result table cell performs a segue to that ViewController. What is wrong is the button position which is moved on the right, out of the navbar.

Pictures of the problem:
[image: The correct case]
[image: The wrong case]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to set a frame for your UIButton:

```
UIButton *menuButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44); // or whatever dimensions
...
```